# How to keep the ordering of key dictionary without sorting in loop?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, for-loop, jinja2

I have a key of dictionary like below:

```
 {% set ReportList = { 
   'T00004' : {'Title': 'Letter of Confirmation Loan'}, 
   'T00002' :{'Title': 'Repayment Schedule'},
   'T00010': {'Title': 'Letter of Hypothec'} } 
  %}
```

I want to loop through this dictionary but I want to keep the order of dictionary as it was without sorting, so it should be in order like this `T00004, T00002, T00010`. Therefore, I tried the following loop.

```
 {%for key in ReportList %} 
 {% set value = ReportList.get(key,{})%}
<tr class="link" onclick="CustomClickView('{{value.Title}}','Template/{{key}}')">
  <td width="10%">{{key}}</td>
  <td width="90%">{{value.Title}}</td>
</tr>
{%endfor%}
```

However, it result as `T00002, T00004, T00010` orderly that was not as I expected above.

How I can keep the ordering of key dictionary without sorting in loop? Thanks.

Comment: `django`? if yes, it might be a good idea to add it in the tag list

Comment: @Adelin, it is `jinja2`

Comment: Consider using OrderedDict

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dictionary, how to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Comment: @Galen, the question is `jinja2` context rather than `pythonic` context. So, it should not duplicated. Thanks.

Comment: @Galen, it did not solve my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy, you just need to pass `OrderedDict` into template, for example:

```
# .py
render("index.html", OrderedDict=OrderedDict)

# .html
{% set ReportList = OrderedDict({ 
   'T00004' : {'Title': 'Letter of Confirmation Loan'}, 
   'T00002' :{'Title': 'Repayment Schedule'},
   'T00010': {'Title': 'Letter of Hypothec'} }) 
%}
```

Then you can use it just like a normal `OrderedDict`.

Comment: that's way is really working as great, Thanks you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint

reportList = { 
   'T00004' : {'Title': 'Letter of Confirmation Loan'}, 
   'T00002' :{'Title': 'Repayment Schedule'},
   'T00010': {'Title': 'Letter of Hypothec'} } 


pprint.pprint(reportList.items())

#  dict_items([
#   ('T00004', {'Title': 'Letter of Confirmation Loan'})
#   ('T00002', {'Title': 'Repayment Schedule'}), 
#   ('T00010', {'Title': 'Letter of Hypothec'})])

for  num,d in reportList.items():
  print(num)

# T00004
# T00002
# T00010
```

Comment: appologise, since the question is `jinja2` rather than `python`, how can we do it in `jinja2` context? Thanks.

Comment: could you add some comment detail rather than only code, since it is a bit difficult to understand its detail what and how it works. Thanks.